# Display active tab's name in an span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to show the active tab's name (text) in a span `.active-class`.
Example:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="feinleinen active"><a href="">feinleinen</a></li>
<li class="glatt"><a href="">glatt</a></li>
</ul > 

<span class="active-class">*Active_Tab_Name_Here (i.e. feinleinen) *</span>
```

Comment: Can you please give a bit more information? Perhaps even a screenshot?
- What are you trying to do?
- What is not working?

Comment: you question doesn't make sense. what does "How to span" mean?

Comment: Maybe [***How do I ask a good question***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would be more approriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzntkjzw/):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="feinleinen active"><a href="">feinleinen</a>

  </li>
  <li class="glatt"><a href="">glatt</a>

  </li>
</ul>

<span class="active-class">active tab name here</span>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.active-class').text($('.tabs .active').find('a').text());
```

I guess you want this on click , therefore bit updation to my above code here :-

```
$('.tabs a').click(function () {
  $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  $('.active-class').text($(this).text()); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is either to have a click event each time a link is clicked and put the text in there?

**Javascript:**

```
function changeSpan(var newText){
    document.getElementByClassName('active-class').innterHTML(newText);
}
```

When the above you need to initialise the function. this can be done in the anchor within the list item.

```
<li><a href='#' onclick='changeSpan("new item name!");'>
```

Don't forget the hash (#) within the href! This stops the default action, in layman's terms.

With **jQuery** this can be a bit simpler

```
$('a','ul.tabs>li').click(function(){//a classname would be a better selector
    $('.active-class').appendTo($(this).innerHTML());//can also use $(this).text();
    return false;//also stops default action
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x97g8sc7/

```
$(".active-class").text($(".tabs .active").text());
```